# Python 'int' object is not callable on For Loop

Tags: python

I know there's been quite a few of these but after looking through them, I wasn't able to solve my issue. I'm also still learning Python so a simple mix up could be happening.

Thus far the error is being reached on the line with the constructed for loop.

```
        # down
        column = 2
        grid = [ 10, 10 ]
        while range > 0:
            # grab at the top
            cur = genes[((grid[1] - 1) * grid[0]) + column]
            prev = cur
            for a in range((grid[1] - 2), -1, -1):
                # start one below from the top
                cur = genes[(a * grid[0]) + column]
                genes[(a * grid[0]) + column] = prev
                prev = cur
            # now apply the change back to the top
            genes[((grid[1] - 1) * grid[0]) + column] = prev
            if get_fitness(genes, grid) > fitness:
                print("After Down")
                board = Board(genes, grid)
                board.print()
                print("-------------------")
                return
            range -= 1
```

As requested

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/tetris.py", line 144, in test_double_block
self.solveDouble([4, 4])
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/tetris.py", line 167, in solveDouble
best = genetic.get_best(fnGetFitness, None, optimalFitness, geneset, 
fnDisplay, custom_mutate=fnCustomMutate, custom_create=fnCreate, maxAge=10)
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/genetic.py", line 105, in get_best
maxAge, poolSize):
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/genetic.py", line 131, in _get_improvement
child = new_child(parent, pindex, parents)
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/genetic.py", line 102, in fnNewChild
return fnMutate(parent)
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/genetic.py", line 74, in fnMutate
return _mutate_custom(parent, custom_mutate, get_fitness)
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/genetic.py", line 47, in _mutate_custom
custom_mutate(childGenes)
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/tetris.py", line 159, in fnCustomMutate
mutate(genes, grid, window)
File "/home/kyle/Documents/Books/GeneticAlgorithms/GA 
Projects/Tetris/tetris.py", line 65, in mutate
for a in range((grid[1] - 2), -1, -1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please show the full error output as well as a [mcve]. e.g. where is `get_fitness` and `genes` and `Board`?

Comment: can you edit your question to include the full traceback of the error

Comment: get_fitness, genes, and Board aren't any reason for an error output as I've been using them frequently and in other variations that this error hasn't come up. Though I have posted the full traceback.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `range` as a number

```
while range > 0:
    ... 
    range -= 1
```

But you later used it as a function

```
for a in range(...):
```

Rename the `range` integer to something else

For example, you could do a backward for loop

```
for r in range(top_range, 0, -1):
    ...
```